# Fancybox showing the same image

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox

I'm having trouble using Fancybox on my website.

These are two (out of 9) of my divs, with different images in it. The thing is, whenever I click on any of the images, it shows the same image everytime. So when I click on the 2nd image, it shows the first image, just like all of the other divs.

```
<a id="single_3" href="Foto's/symposium1_groot.png" title="Test">
<div id="symposium1"> <img src="Foto's/symposium1.jpg" alt="" /></div></a>
</a>

<a id="single_3" href="Foto's/symposium2_groot.png" title="Test">
<div id="symposium2"> <img src="Foto's/symposium2.jpg" alt="" /></div></a>
```

Comment: Use *class* instead of IDs. DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/h4EYP/... and check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support ==>FAQ tab ==> No.6.

Comment: yes, did that, and it's still not working, my html/js/css looks like this right now: jsfiddle.net/E67wN

Comment: You have a css issue, this `#symposium2 {padding-left: 750px;...}` in an `absolute` positioned element is covering the previous element making it unreachable. If you do `#symposium2 {left: 750px;...}` then it should work. See http://jsfiddle.net/4VJEW/

Comment: This seemed to be working, but after changing a few divs it just stopped working and went back to the old problem.. http://jsfiddle.net/pE7Vw/

Comment: Well, you are still using `padding` (`padding-top: 110px;`) in `absolute` positioned elements. Use `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` to position them, not `padding`

Comment: for some reason.. the first two images are working now, the others won't pop up

Comment: Okay it's working now, i forgot to change some of the id's to classes. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make ids unique. Also having 2 closing `</a>` tags for the first block probably isn't good for you.

Try:

```
<a id="single_3" href="Foto's/symposium1_groot.png" title="Test">
    <div id="symposium1"> <img src="Foto's/symposium1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</a>

<a id="single_4" href="Foto's/symposium2_groot.png" title="Test">
    <div id="symposium2"> <img src="Foto's/symposium2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Hm, Okay, what do I do to the javascript? Since it refers to 'single_3', and now the same javascript needs to refer to single_3,single_4,single_5, etc.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    $('#single_3').fancybox({
        openEffect : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'outside'
            }
        }
    });
});

Comment: You can add a common class name between the links that you want it to happen on.

Something like `<a class="single">` then do `$('.single').fancybox(...)`

Comment: Still not working..     $(".single").fancybox({



<a class="single" href="Foto's/symposium1_groot.png" title="Test">
<div id="symposium1"> <img src="Foto's/symposium1.jpg" alt="" /></div></a>


I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: The only difference that would be in the fancybox JS code from your first comment would be `#single_3` would change to `.single` and the `<a>` tags in your HTML would just have a `class="single"` on them.

So something like:
`$(document).ready(function() { $(".fancybox").fancybox(); $('.single').fancybox({ openEffect : 'elastic', closeEffect : 'none', helpers : { title : { type : 'outside' } } }); });` would be the JS to accompany your HTML

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did but when I click on an image, instead of popping up, the image opens in the same window and I'm still having the 'same image' issue..

Comment: This is what it looks like right now (I know the jsfiddle isn't working, created this just to show you) :

http://jsfiddle.net/E67wN/